# Respuesta contiene \n cuando deberia estar vacia, al hacer consulta a mysql con android y volley

Tags: android, android-volley

estoy haciendo un login con android y volley de manera que al pulsar el boton "login" comprueba (mediante un servicio web, con su correspondiente archivo php que da el servicio) si el usuario esta en la base de datos y en caso positivo hace el login. Todo funciona bien pero me he encontrado que la respuesta que obtengo en el metodo `public void onResponse(String response)` ,cuando no encuentra el usuario en la base de datos, deberia estar vacia y en cambio contiene un `\n`. No es problema del php ya que he probado a no mandar ningun dato desde el php y el `response` contiene siempre un `\n`. Cuando encuentra al usuario en la base de datos funciona perfectamente pero cuando no, como ya dije, en lugar de estar vacia contiente un `\n`, ¿es eso normal? ¿hay algo que se pueda hacer para que no contenga ese `\n`?
este es el codigo de la funcion que hace ese trabajo:

```
private void validarUsuario(String URL)
{
    private void validarUsuario(String URL)
{

    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //if(!response.isEmpty())
            if(!response.isEmpty() && !response.equals("\n"))
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PrincipalActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o contraseña incorrectas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })

    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parametros= new HashMap<String,String>();
            parametros.put("email",email.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("password",password.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }

    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.getCache().clear();
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //if(!response.isEmpty())
            if(!response.isEmpty() && !response.equals("\n"))
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PrincipalActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o contraseña incorrectas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    })

    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parametros= new HashMap<String,String>();
            parametros.put("email",email.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("password",password.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }

    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.getCache().clear();
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

y este es el codigo del servicio php:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email=? AND password=?");
$sentencia->bind_param('ss',$email,$password);
$sentencia->execute();

$resultado = $sentencia->get_result();
if($fila =mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
$sentencia->close();
$conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: Muéstranos tu código PHP. Es muy probable que esos saltos de línea se te están escapando en tu entorno de servidor. Considera que [un BOM](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark) (no visible a simple vista), un bloque mal cerrado, un echo, un error o advertencia en el servidor, un bloque HTML, o lo que sea emitirá una salida y esa podría ser la causa.

Comment: ya he editado el post y he añadido el codigo del servicio php.

Comment: Tu código puede estar levantando algún error o advertencia. Para saber con exactitud lo que está respondiendo el servidor, puedes poner al principio del método `onResponse` lo siguiente: `Log.d("ABC",response);` luego lanza de nuevo tu petición y revisa el Logcat para ver lo que imprime al lado de ABC. Supongo que sabes usar el Logcat. De todos modos, aunque no haya filas, deberías mandar algo que luego verificarías del lado de Android, por ejemplo, puedes hacer un `echo "error";` y en Android verificar si el servidor respondió `error`. También, conviene poner `exit();` luego del `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hay comunicación entre cliente y servidor conviene tener en cuenta varias cosas:

1. En el servidor debes controlar el código en todo momento, de modo que éste devuelva **unicamente aquello que estás esperando**. En ese sentido, revisa también lo que ocurre en tu archivo `conexion.php`. Espero que allí no salga nada por pantalla, que si no hay conexión devuelvas `null` y que controles aquí si la conexión no es nula.
2. En el cliente debes verificar lo que respondió el servidor de acuerdo a una lógica o contrato. De hecho, en tu implementación el cliente hay un fallo en ese sentido. ¿Qué ocurre si la consulta SQL no encuentra datos por ejemplo? ¿Qué ocurre si hay cualquier otro error (de lógica, no de red o de servidor)? Volley no controla esos errores, debes hacerlo tú.

Aplicando lo dicho, aunque habría que ver lo que tienes en `conexion.php` para terminar de afinar el código del todo, te muestro un ejemplo de código controlado y con un contraro entre cliente y servidor que dice: *cuando haya datos, mándame los datos, cuando haya error, mándame una cadena que diga `error`*:

#### PHP

```
<?php
    # Usamos fusión de null para verificar POST   
    $email=$_POST['email'] ?? null;
    $password=$_POST['password'] ?? null;
    if ($email && $password) {
        include 'conexion.php';
        $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email=? AND password=?";
        $sentencia=$conexion->prepare($sql);
        $sentencia->bind_param('ss',$email,$password);
        $sentencia->execute();
        $resultado = $sentencia->get_result();
        if($resultado && $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            $mData=json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            $sentencia->close();
            $conexion->close();
        } else {
            # No hay datos
            $mData="error";
    } else {
        #Faltan datos en el POST
        $mData="error";
    }
    echo trim($mData);
    exit();
?>
```

---

#### Android

```
        if(!response.isEmpty() && !response.equals("error"))
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PrincipalActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o contraseña incorrectas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Así debería funcionar.

Particularmente yo prefiero usar `JSONObjectRequest`, porque desde el servidor puedes responder un JSON que, en el caso de éxito podrás mapear fácilmente a tu modelo de datos, y en el caso de error puedes colocar, más que una simple cadena `error`, un mensaje personalizado que incorporarías a tu política de manejo de errores, informando al usuario adecuadamente si fuera preciso.

De hecho, aquí tú le dices al usuario *Usuario o contraseña incorrectas*. Pero eso no será necesariamente **cierto**. El usuario por ejemplo puedo haber ingresado sus datos correctamente, pero pudo haber un error (por ejemplo, la base de datos está down en ese momento). El usuario se subirá por las paredes y hará quien sabe qué pensando que sus credenciales no son correctas, cuando no lo son. Digo esto para subrayar que **el manejo de errores es fundamental en una aplicación** y por lo general se le da muy poca importancia.

Si tu código sigue sin funcionar, revisa lo que hay en `conexion.php` y/o haz una depuración en Android de la respuesta, imprimiendo en el Logcat el valor de `respuesta`  o poniendo puntos de interrupción en el código y usando el depurador para verificar el estado y contenido de los objetos en cada punto importante del código.